# What happened to symbolicatecrash? (MIA from Xcode 3.2.3)

Tags: iphone, xcode, symbolicatecrash

I installed Xcode 3.2.3 and the symbolicatecrash console utility that used to live here:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneRemoteDevice.xcodeplugin/Contents/Resources/symbolicatecrash
```

is no longer there. Yes, yes, I know that reaching into random packages is dangerous business if you expect things to stay where they are, but has anyone found this utility's new home? I hope it still exists somewhere as a command-line tool.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You know, you can just type

```
locate symbolicatecrash
```

in the Terminal to find it. The file is now in

> `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash`

Comment: Thanks for both dinner and the fishing lesson.